# Restoring android studio sdk update sites

Tags: android, android-studio

In my anroid studio 1.5.1 latest stable version as of now, I see that some of the URLS in SDK manager -> SDK update sites are no longer accessible and are shown with error icon. My android studio is from the stable channel and latest version not sure if these URLS have been changed by Google ?

The reason why this is causing me concern is that Doze feature is not working on my Marshmellow images and I want to ensure I have most recent images but then I found the above mentioned issue in the SDK manager,

Picture attached below, please advise any fix for this..

[image]